# kotlin coroutineScope exception cannot be handled

Tags: kotlin, exception, coroutine

Hi I'm playing around kotlin and I want to catch and throw our the exception, so my code is like this

```
            runBlocking {
                coroutineScope {
                    nonNullRecords.forEach {
                        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                            val time = measureTimeMillis {
                                try {
                                    process(it)
                                } catch (e: Exception) {
                                    throw Exception(e)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

the process function is s suspend function.

So the thing is that in this case, if the process function has an exception(which is HttpTimeoutException), my service will crash which is excepted. But if I don't use the try catch, then my service will ignore the exception.
and further more, if I use `throw e` instead of `throw Exception(e)`, it will also ignore the exception
May I know how this works? thanks so much

Comment: What is the `HttpTimeoutException` you're talking about? Could you please provide the fully qualified name? It might extend `CancellationException` - which is the exception used by coroutines for cancellation mechanisms, which would explain why it is ignored

Comment: in the ```process(it)``` function, it will return ```io.ktor.client.features.HttpRequestTimeoutException: Request timeout has been expired ```, so if I dont try catch the ```process(it)``` , this exception will not cause the service down, not sure why

Answer (score 1):

This is because Ktor's `HttpRequestTimeoutException` extends `CancellationException`, which is an exception used internally by coroutines to implement the cancellation mechanism. This is why this particular exception is not considered a real problem and is silently ignored.

This was fixed and will be released in Ktor 2.0.0:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-3192